# Different comparisons between de Rham and singular cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold. I am aware of two comparison isomorphisms $H^*_{dR}(X,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^*_{sing}(X,\mathbb{R})$ between de Rham cohomology and singular cohomology (with real coefficients).

The first comparison isomorphism (due to de Rham) is given by integrating smooth $k$-forms against smooth $k$-cycles (and then one has to argue that singular cohomology can be calculated with smooth $k$-chains).

The second comparison isomorphism is given by interpreting both cohomology groups as cohomology of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{R}$ on $X$. Indeed, the de Rham complex and the sheafified complex of singular cochains both give acyclic resolutions of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{R}$ on $X$.

Do these two comparison isomorphisms coincide? (A reference is plenty sufficient.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. This question also came up on MathOverflow:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444010

with some references linked there. Another reference is 5.36 in "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups" by Frank Warner (also the rest of Section 5 there).

A key point is that the "de Rham map" given by integration of $k$-forms against $k$-cycles gives a morphism from the de Rham complex to the sheafified complex of smooth singular cochains ("Stokes's theorem").